# WordprocessingDocument.Close() throwing IsolatedStorageException

Tags: openxml, openxml-sdk

I am building up a chart with 582 literal data points. When I call WordprocessingDocument.Close() I get an IsolatedStorageException.

This doesn't make sense to me because the OpenXML SDK, as I understand it, is totally self contained writing data to a stream. There's no calls to Office or anything else that could hit this issue.

Be that as it may, is there anything I can do to avoid this issue?

thanks - dave

Comment: Are you using OpenXml version 2.5 (or below)?

Comment: Can u try to apply using statement? What's the result of it?

Comment: I'm using version 2.7.2

Answer (score 2):

I did some research into the `IsolatedStorageException` related to large XLSX files and found solutions to your problem.

According to [Eric White's blog](http://ericwhite.com/blog/announcing-the-release-of-a-new-system-io-packaging-implementation/), when *legacy* OpenXml generates a file larger than 10M it needs to take advantage of Isolated Storage.  If mulitple threads access the Isolated Storage during report generation System.IO.Packaging will throw the `IsolatedStorageException`.

This is because the System.IO.Packaging that is baked into .NET was not written well enough to handle these scenarios.  That System.IO.Packaging can't be changed.

To remedy this issue, you can try one of these solutions:

1. Refactor your code to use a new OpenXml built on a System.IO.Packaging that Eric White refactored to remove the Isolated Storage depedency.  [Check this chart](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#windowsbase-or-systemiopackaging) for reference and use the correct NuGet command to bring in the new version without the WindowsBase dependency.
2. Don't refactor your OpenXml code, but change your report generation user interface to prohibit (if possible) or discourage generating files larger than 10M.
3. If your OpenXml code is embedded inside an IIS based web solution and refactoring your code is not feasible, try one of the solutions [provided by this blog](http://support.gemboxsoftware.com/kb/articles/isolatedstorageexception-when-writing-a-large-xslx-files).  These techniques aim to provide permissions needed by IIS to try and get around this exception and might not be related to Eric White's concern.

Without more information about your solution architecture, these are the solutions I can recommend at this time.  Hope they help.